# Create new column that increments based on row sequence in R

Tags: r

I would like to add a column to a data frame (let's call the data frame "df"). As demonstrated, I would like the new column (df$X3, below) to start at 1 and increment by 1 when X2 is populated **and** when X1 [of the previous row] is populated. I've found a few similar examples, but can't quite get this one. Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

df:

```
X1  X2  X3
    A   1
    G   1
    B   1
X       1
Y       1
Z       1
    E   2
    U   2
A       2
C       2
E       2
    A   3
    A   3
    A   3
    A   3
C       3
E       3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), check for blank elements in 'X2' to get a logical vector, take the difference, convert to logical vector (`< 0`) and get the `cumsum`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, X3 := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(X2=='')<0))]
df1
#    X1 X2 X3
# 1:     A  1
# 2:     G  1
# 3:     B  1
# 4:  X     1
# 5:  Y     1
# 6:  Z     1
# 7:     E  2
# 8:     U  2
# 9:  A     2
#10:  C     2
#11:  E     2
#12:     A  3
#13:     A  3
#14:     A  3
#15:     A  3
#16:  C     3
#17:  E     3
```

If both 'X1' and 'X2' have `''` in the same row, and we need `X3` to be also `''`

```
 setDT(df1)[, X3 := as.character(cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(X2=='')<0)))
      ][X1=='' & X2=='', X3 := '']
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X1 = c("", "", "", "X", "Y", "Z", "", "", "A", 
"C", "E", "", "", "", "", "C", "E"), X2 = c("A", "G", "B", "", 
"", "", "E", "U", "", "", "", "A", "A", "A", "A", "", "")),
.Names = c("X1", 
"X2"), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: how does this work without even looking at `X1`? I think the case with a blank in both columns would skew this?

Comment: @Chris Based on the data showed by the OP, the X2 starts at intervals after X1 ends.  It is not clear to me whether the OP have other patterns or not.

Comment: Works like a charm! One caveat: Empty cells must actually be empty (i.e., "") and not NA. Thanks!